# Jenkins MultiBranchPipeline Failing with ModelInterpreter.groovy: 43: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.Nonnull

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am trying to setup a multi branch pipeline between Github and Jenkins. I am working on a spring boot project and I have setup my local jdk and maven within Jenkins.

I am running the pipeline using jenkinsfile, the pipeline code is as below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkins is able to scan my repo successfully, however on running the pipeline I am getting below error which I am clueless about. Could you please help me in breaking this barrier I am stuck at this.

```
16:35:38 Connecting to https://api.github.com using shred22/****** (Git Hub Credentials)
Obtained Jenkinsfile from ab4673fa1cc076e4ce773fbc2be9c3756aac0bc8
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 43: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.Nonnull
 @ line 43, column 1.
   import javax.annotation.Nonnull
   ^

jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 42: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.CheckForNull
 @ line 42, column 1.
   import javax.annotation.CheckForNull
   ^

jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 455: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.CheckForNull ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 455, column 30.
       def withCredentialsBlock(@CheckForNull Environment environment, Closure body) {
                                ^

jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 493: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.Nonnull ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 493, column 13.
               @Nonnull Map<String, CredentialWrapper> credentials) {
               ^

4 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:250)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.recompile(GroovyClassLoader.java:766)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:718)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$TimingLoader.loadClass(CpsGroovyShell.java:170)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelStepLoader.getValue(ModelStepLoader.java:60)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the upstream issue.
I worked around by downgrading **Pipeline: Groovy package** to v2.80 from v2.81. (However, the PR is ready in upstream so I believe v2.82 will be released soon.)

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62988
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/pull/397

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'll try this and updatey findings here. !!!

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around the problem by removing the two imports and the annotations from the coded in ModelInterpreter.groovy in the jar file and replacing the jar file. That makes it work, since the annotations are optional it will probably not cause problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, So when will be the fix be available? I encountered this issue on Jenkins 2.235.1

Comment: I am in no way connected the project, I have no idea what they do

Comment: I get that.. Thanks a lot for the Suggestion. I got it working by downgrading the installed jenkins version. !!